# disgusting with or disgusted with

Tags: word-meaning

Both of them are Adjectives in the following examples:

> I am *sort of disgusting with* his flattery. 
>   I am *sort of disgusted with* his flattery.

I came up with the first sentence because I saw this:

> Song Yi is *sort of disgusting with* her obsession with Kim Jun.

I still have one more question as to the part of speech of *sort of*. I think it is Noun, with the meaning *type/ kind*. Therefore, *disgusting/ disgusted with* will be Complement for *sort of*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the former, I would prefer:

> I am ***sort of disgusted by*** his flattery.

The flattering is disgusting to you; ergo, you are disgusted *by* it.

> Song Yi is *sort of disgusting with* her obsession with Kim Jun.

is logically equivalent to:

> I am *sort of disgusted by* Song Yi's obsession with Kim Jun.

The use of "with" in the first one is a bit confusing. It's actually not connected to "disgusting" in the way you think! It begins a second part of the sentence which explains *why* Song Yi is considered to be somewhat disgusting. There are a few ways to make this more obvious through punctuation (add a comma before "with", for example), but I think it's easier and more clear to simply rewrite the sentence as:

> Song Yi's obsession with Kim Jun is sort of disgusting to me.

---

"Sort of" modifies *the amount to which the subject is disgusted*. All of the example sentences would be fine without "sort of" anywhere in them.

> Song Yi is disgusting with her obsession with Kim Jun.

This is 100% disgust.

> Song Yi is *sort of* disgusting with her obsession with Kim Jun.

This is much less disgust. It's as though the speaker is saying "Yeah, I suppose she is somewhat disgusting, but it could be worse."